# C# VSTO Outlook 2016: Modify hyperlink embedded in image

Tags: c#, email, hyperlink, outlook

As part of a real time sentiment project, I have an outlook signature that is made up of a combination of happy, sad and neutral face, each of which has an embedded hyperlink associated to it (this is done within the signature functionality of Outlook).

Example "happy" hyperlink looks like this: http://x.x.x.x/happy?sr=000000000.

Using VSTO, I extract the real SR number in the email Subject and replace the "000000000" in the hyperlink with the SR number. I figured out how to extract the SR number from the subject using regex, but when I try to replace the "000000000" in mail.Body (mail.Body.Replace), it works but I lose the graphs (ie happy/sad/neutral faces). So all I see in the email that gets sent are 3 hyperlinks.

My code looks like this:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(^|\D)(\d{9})($|\D)");
if (mail != null)
{
    Match m = regex.Match(mail.Subject);
    if (m.Success)
    {
         Group g = m.Groups[0];
         mail.Subject += " !!Found " + g + "  in subject.";
         mail.Body.Replace("000000000", g.ToString());
    }
    ...
```

I'm want to be able to pass the SR # in the hyperlink so that my web server can use it in the user feedback.

My question is how can I replace the 000000000 in the hyperlinks without losing the graphical portion of my signature (happy, sad, neutral faces)?

Thank you,
Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This newbie didn't realize C# didn't do in-place substitution :(

```
mail.HTMLBody = mail.HTMLBody.Replace("000000000", g.ToString());
```

fixed the problem.